# glTexImage2D - GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV and compressed internal format

Tags: opengl

I have modified a legacy code (OpenGL 2.1) which uses glTexImage2D with GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV texture target. I have noticed that when I set some compressed internal format, for example GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT it doesn't work with GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV (I get a white texture). I have tested other scenarios and everything works fine, i.e. GL_TEXTURE_2D with compressed internal format, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV with non-compressed internal format. Does it mean that GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV can't be used with compressed formats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the [spec for `NV_texture_rectangle` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_texture_rectangle.txt) says about compressed formats:

```
Can compressed texture images be specified for a rectangular texture?

      RESOLUTION:  The generic texture compression internal formats
      introduced by ARB_texture_compression are supported for rectangular
      textures because the image is not presented as compressed data and
      the ARB_texture_compression extension always permits generic texture
      compression internal formats to be stored in uncompressed form.
      Implementations are free to support generic compression internal
      formats for rectangular textures if supported but such support is
      not required.

      This extensions makes a blanket statement that specific compressed
      internal formats for use with CompressedTexImage<n>DARB are NOT
      supported for rectangular textures.  This is because several
      existing hardware implementations of texture compression formats
      such as S3TC are not designed for compressing rectangular textures.
      This does not preclude future texture compression extensions from
      supporting compressed internal formats that do work with rectangular
      extensions (by relaxing the current blanket error condition).
```

So your specific format `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT` is not necessarily supported as being the one mentioned to be "not designed for compressing rectangular textures".